# python get all possible words from list of alphabets

Tags: python

Lets say I have some alphabets and numbers in my text file `alphabets.txt`

```
A B E G L I P c e f u y 2 8 9 6
```

I want to open this file which I can do from

```
f = open("/home/someuser/Documents/alphabets.txt")
for word in f.read().split():
    print(word)
```

But I want the random words to be printed from those alphabets.

I want  words starting with 8 characters with every alphabets in it. Like permutation combination

None any word should be left from combination none should be repeated. 
How can I do this ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, at least not of that other question. As I understand the question, repeated characters are allowed, but the only answer to that question does not mention `product`, but only `combinations` and `permutations`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product` to get all the combinations.

```
>>> alphabet = "ABCDEF"
>>> words = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3)]
>>> words
['AAA', 'AAB', ... 'FFE', 'FFF']
>>> len(words)
216
```

For getting random words, you can `random.shuffle` that list and `pop` elements from it (no repeats), or use `random.choice` (with repeats)

```
>>> random.choice(words)
'EFA'
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> words.pop()
'CAD'
```

However, exhaustively generating all the 4,294,967,296 eight-letter-words from your alphabet will take very long. If you just need a few random samples, it would be simpler to just join 8 random letters from the alphabet.

```
>>> [''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(8)) for _ in range(5)]
['28GLIGB9', 'PE8uyLue', '6c8eGByA', 'BLucIuuf', 'fEeBf9Bf']
```